# MG996R jittering

Tags: servo, robotics

I'm working on a project of a camera connected to a robotic arm that moves when my face is about to get out of the frame.
I'm using 3 Tower Pro MG996R servos and they are connected to my raspberry pi.
for some reason whenever I do a simple command like:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(2,GPIO.OUT)
x = GPIO.PWM(3,50)
x.start(0)
x.ChangeDutyCycle(8)
sleep(0.5)
x.stop()
GPIO.cleanup()
```

My servo will finish moving but at the end of the movement, it will jitter for about a second.
Sometimes it will jitter and sometimes it won't. I couldn't find what makes it jitter.
Would love to get some help on that.
Thanks a lot.

Edit:
I also tried using gpiozero and changing its Factory to pigpio pin factory.
Sadly still jittering.

```
from gpiozero import Servo
from time import sleep
from gpiozero.pins.pigpio import PiGPIOFactory

factory = PiGPIOFactory()
servo = Servo(3,pin_factory = factory)
servo.mid()
sleep()
servo.min()
sleep()
servo.max()
sleep()
servo.value = None
```

Comment: Does it jitter with pigs?  Try `sudo pigpiod` then `pigs s 3 1500`.

Comment: I wrote exactly that right now and it jittered

Comment: Add a photo of the wiring.  Perhaps you haven't connected the grounds, or the servo is faulty, or something else is using GPIO3.

Comment: The wires are connected correctly I checked 100 times. But I suspect the cause of the problem is because I connected the servos directly to the raspberry pi. Does that make any sense (The problem persists even when 1 servo is connected)? I will take a picture of it soon, it's a big mess.